# How to speed up ffmpeg's copy?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently using ffmpegs concat with -c copy. I am  getting around 3.7x on average.

```
$ ffmpeg -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,tcp,http,pipe -f concat -i - -c copy "test.mp4"
........
frame=24457 fps=237 q=-1.0 Lsize= 2983723kB time=00:06:48.02 bitrate=59905.3kbits/s speed=3.96x
........
```

But the issue is, every session I have around 9x15x8min clips to merge. So if I could improve the speed of copy I would like to.

I am not sure if you can use gpu as no encoding is happening. But I should be able to assign more cores to the process?

I have somewhere in this image stopped the ffmpeg process, but you would never know when it was. It was 9 seconds ago in the image.
[image]

ffmpeg -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,tcp,http,pipe -f concat -i - -c copy "test.mp4"

#### Full Command

```
ls -1v | grep -i mp4 | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/\n$//; print "file '"'"'$_'"'"'\n"' | ffmpeg -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist file,tcp,http,pipe -f concat -i - -c copy "test.mp4"
```

### with ffmpeg process running for 60+ seconds

[image]

Comment: This process is I/O limited. CPU hardly comes into it, unless it's being burdened elsewhere. Based on the stats line you showed, ffmpeg is writing out at 60 x 4 = 240 mbps = 30 mB/s. Are your inputs/output on same drive?

Comment: ahh you genius!!! I am from the same drive a ide drive too. I'll write to my nmve drive and see the improvement.

Comment: Wow... you were right. speed 10x now. So in theory I need to put the drives on the faster drive first, then move once them concat'd!

Comment: Well damm... on my main mvm drive I get speeds of `144x`

Comment: Off topic: what app do you use to generate those CPU usage graphs?

Comment: Its called "System Monitor": https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor

Comment: Provided you have enough RAM, you could also use a TMPFS - it should even be faster. Would be, for example : mount a temp folder, keep source files on disk (to not lose them) and have the temporary (concatenated) file built in that temp folder (so in case of a crash, no real loss), then move it once finished. `mount -t tmpfs -o size=16G tmpfs ./tmp`